# Get input from UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm doing a programatic UI for my iOS app, and I have these two `UITextField`s. When the client opens the app, they'll select the two fields and give some input, after that, how do I deselect the `UITextField`s? Because if you tap or scroll somewhere else on the screen, the keyboard stays on the screen - it doesn't retract like the expected behavior.

So I guess my question is how do you submit a `UITextField` without a `nib` or `storyboard`?

Here's the relevant part of `viewDidLoad`, with the two `UITextField`s:

```
UITextField *loginField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:mistarFrame];
loginField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
loginField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
loginField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20];
loginField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
loginField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
loginField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
loginField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
loginField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Student ID" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
[header addSubview:loginField];

UITextField *passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(mistarFrame.origin.x, (mistarFrame.origin.y + iconHeight), mistarFrame.size.width, mistarFrame.size.height)];
passwordField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
passwordField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
passwordField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20];
passwordField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
passwordField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
passwordField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
passwordField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
passwordField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Password" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
passwordField.secureTextEntry = YES;
[header addSubview:passwordField];
```

Comment: Why not respond to the Return key on the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can conform to UITextFieldDelegate protocol and set

```
loginField.delegate = self;
passwordField.delegate = self;
```

and then implement

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if ([loginField.text isEqualToString:@""] == NO && [passwordField.text isEqualToString:@""] == NO) {
        //submit...
    }
    return YES;
}
```

That's if you want to submit by pressing return on the keyboard.

Here's a sample implementation file...

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 100, 25)];
    [self.view addSubview:tf];
    tf.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"Submit");
    }
    return YES;
 }

@end
```

Comment: I tried doing that, it didn't work. My project file is in the two links [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596881/get-input-from-uitextfield/22597569?noredirect=1#comment34405613_22596954), could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I neglected to mention you should return YES in tesxtFieldShouldReturn: and also that textField.text is always not nil once the textFieldhas been initialised so you just check if it's empty or not. Using isEqualToString:@"" == NO is another way of doing what Filip underneath.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your view where the UITextViews are located and hook up a "hide keyboard event" to the tap action.

For example, if the UITextViews are in the view of a UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *screenTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    screenTapped.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:screenTapped];
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that works for dismissing the keyboard, how would I get the input the client entered into the `UITextField`?

Comment: By accessing the property of the textfields. E.g. `NSString *passwordInput = passwordField.text;`

Comment: So I'd put that in the interface, but how would I know the user has entered information?

Comment: if (passwordField.text.length > 0) { // the field is not empty }

Comment: It isn't returning true. [Here](https://github.com/AndrewSB/MistarApp/blob/master/MistarApp/MistarApp/MistarApp/MAController.m#L161) are the two `UITextField`s and [here's](https://github.com/AndrewSB/MistarApp/blob/master/MistarApp/MistarApp/MistarApp/MAController.m#L242) the `passwordField.text.length > 0` bool function. I also called the function inside `viewDidLoad`, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [loginField resignFirstResponder];
    //..
}
```

Try this.